Is it possible to add arbitrary amounts of quantum resistance cheaply?
There are a number of mostly lattice based quantum resistant asymmetric algorithms, but I was wondering if there are any easy ways to augment the "normal" algorithms (e.g. RSA, eliptic curves) to require extra qbits to crack.
Specifically, is there a way to add $\mathcal{O}(n)$ qbits to an asymmetric decryption algorithm at an $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ (or even better $\mathcal{O}(n)$) cost? If so, it seems like this might be an interesting intermediate step between fully quantum resistant cryptography and currently deployed methods.

There is no way to do this.
Under Shor's attack the Discrete Logarithm in a group of size $2^n$ has quantum complexity $\mathrm{poly}(n).$
If we consider extending the bitlength by $n^c$ bits as $O(n^c)$ cost for some constant $c$ the resulting quantum complexity would be
$$
\mathrm{poly}(n^c)=\mathrm{poly}(n).
$$
A similar argument applies to RSA.

No, for the reasons indicated in the other answer to this question.
But I want to point out a partial stopgap measure when it comes to signature: using Schnorr groups with large parameter $p$ (e.g. 16384-bit $p$, 256-bit $q$) for Schnorr signature or DSA. Notice that public key size increases as $\log_2 p$ (grows to 2KiB), but signature size depends only on $\log_2 q$ (it stays 64 bytes, or 48 bytes for original/short Schnorr signature), contrary to what happens for RSA with large public modulus. Thus this is practical in many applications where signature size is a hard constraint (e.g. signed QR codes): computation time for both signature and verification grows slower than $(\log p)^2$, and often remains bearable with the current state of the art in classical computing.
I find likely that such large Schnorr group cryptosystems would fall to hypothetical Cryptographically Relevant Quantum Computers some years after 256-bit Elliptic Curves cryptosystems would. Argument: the attack boils down to solving a DLP in groups of comparable size $q\approx2^{256}$, and can be attacked using comparable quantum algorithms (e.g. Shor's: finding the period of a function $f:(x_1,x_2)\mapsto g^{x_1} y^{x_2}$ evaluated quantumly, with $x_1,x_2$ in the order of $q$). The difference is that each group operation in the Schnorr group requires resources that grow somewhere between $\log(p+\log p)$ and $(\log p)^2$, suggesting correspondingly more error-corrected qubits. I believe that the number of qubits in CRQCs would progress at a moderate pace over the years, much as the number of uncorrected qubits and their coherence time has been doing over the past 25 years for Quantum Computers with no cryptographic relevance.
The fun thing is that we moved from DSA to ECDSA to save on classical computation time and space (also public key size) for signature computation and verification, at equal signature size. And the fear of CRQC makes it sensible to go back, because the bearable extra work on classical computers would give some practical resilience.
Perhaps not coincidentally: in 2016 the NIST kept 3072-bit RSA and DSA in the Commercial National Security Algorithms, and stopped suggesting migration of existing such systems to EC-based cryptography. Their revised suggestion was (and AFAIK remains) to prepare for swift migration to Quantum-Resistant cryptography when available. Perhaps they estimate like me that, at equal signature size, properly implemented DSA is safer than ECDSA against hypothetical CRQC.

I'm not sure that coherence time is a relevant parameter here - afaik errors can be supressed exponentially (i.e coherence time increased exponentially) by increasing the code distance of logical qubits linearly. Increasing code distance linearly will increase the number of physical qubits required at most polynomially (e.g as d^2 for the surface code). After gate fidelities drop below the threshold required for QEC, it's just a matter of number of physical qubits you have and gate speed. But your overall point still stands, of course

The above comment applies to this earlier version of the answer. @TuomasLaakkonen: I understand your point that it was dubious to invoke coherence time for error-corrected qubits, and I modified the answer accordingly. I now invoke coherence time for bare qubits only.
